# Users and Privilages in Mysql Workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

What could be the reason for the following cause. "I did press the revoke privileges button"
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [REVOKE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/revoke.html) statement enables system administrators to revoke privileges from MySQL accounts.

With this, you deleted all the privileges of your user like global, database, table, column, and routine privileges for the user.

The database administrator must provide the privileges of your user with [GRANT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/grant.html) command.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'myuser'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Comment: Thank You @Lucas Henrique for the quick response but, I am getting an error as "error code 1045: Access denied for user root@localhost (using Password:Yes)" 
I actually know the password for the root but, I am not able to pass through.

Comment: @Pelay Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12085022/yes-another-mysql-error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost